# I puchased a new iMac and there is one entry in my contacts app that no longer works with Messages

Tags: macos, imac, messages, contacts

I recently bought a new iMac running Catalina and I used Migration Assistant to load some of my old stuff on my new computer.  This appears to have worked well and my new computer is running fine. There is a problem however. I have several contacts that I text with a few times a week. One contact however doesn't work. I always get a return notice on the messages I send. I can use this contact on my iphone and my iPad and the messages go thru. But it doesn't work using my computer. The other contacts I communicate with work fine from my computer. So I'm lost on what to do. I've tried restarting Messages and restarting my iMac. Neither helped. I also made a new contact card but that didn't help either. Does anyone have an idea of what I can try to do to fix this?  thanks.

Comment: Hmm, long shot it’s [forwarding for a contact that’s only SMS?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/402418/5472)

Comment: Woah! So glad. No harm in answering here so you can make a check mark. Different people will search for this issue with different words, so no harm in having a few questions to cover the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer from bmike. It is given [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7714752) and [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/402417/messages-app-on-macos-wont-send-receive-display-messages-to-from-one-specific-c). In words the method to solve the problem is:

From you iphone:

1. Open Settings.
2. Scroll down to Messages
3. Tap on 'Message Forwarding'.
   Ensure that all the devices are selected.